# Quantidade de linhas por pagina reporter viewer c#

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Gostaria de saber como exibir no relatório (reporter viewer/c#)  o número de linhas por páginas e a quantidade total em todas as páginas do relatório.

Comment: A resposta dada não foi satisfatória ?

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Infelizmente o "reportviewer" não funciona dessa forma. Ele mesmo determina a quantidade de informações que serão exibidas na pagina.

Caso que necessite de funcionalidades a mais, recomento você utilizar o "crystalreports" (http://www.crystalreports.com/) ou activereports (https://activereports.grapecity.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Vi sua pergunta e sim existe maneira de você saber o numero de linhas, a pagina e o numero total de paginas. Esta dentro de functions.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]